# Issues with Socket.IO with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, express, socket.io

**Another update:**

The problem occurs when running on localhost as well. Since I figured out the problem comes from the proxy server, here's its code :

```
var serverBouncer = bouncy(function(req, res, bounce) {
    var path = req.url;
    var url = req.headers.host;
    if (typeof url !== "string")
        return;
    var urlArray = url.split('.');
    var bouncePort = port;
    if (!isNaN(urlArray[0]))
        bouncePort = parseInt(urlArray[0]);
    else if (String(urlArray[0]).toLowerCase() === "www" && !isNaN(urlArray[1]))
        bouncePort = parseInt(urlArray[1]);
    bounce(bouncePort);
});
serverBouncer.listen(80);
```

---

**Update:**

I found where the problem came from!!! But I still need to find the solution... There seems to be issues with using newer versions of Socket.io (>= 1.0) with a proxy server (bouncy, in my case).

---

I recently updated Socket.IO from v0.9.16 to v1.4.5, as well as adding Express to the mix. However, now I cannot open multiple (number seems to vary) tabs in Chrome and Firefox without experiencing strange issues (Edge is the only one to work well). It either hangs, or partially loads html and other resources before it hangs.

After waiting, I often get the error :
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

When I close one of the tab that's been hanging, it unblocks the other tabs that were also hanging.

The issues were not present before going through with the changes listed above.

I've been doing research for 2 full days and just now decided to post this, as I know it's very vague and I'm probably not providing enough information. As much as I'd like to, it would take a very long time to remember and list everything I tried during that time.

Using Windows 10 with Chrome v51.0.2704.103, Firefox v43.0.1. The server (CentOS) is using node v6.2.2 with *mainly* the following modules :

- express@4.14.0
- npm@3.9.5
- socket.io@1.4.5

Here's some relevant server code :

```
var port = 8502;    
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var express = require("express");
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //Returning index.html
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    //Some events...
});
```

Here's a bit of the client code :

```
var client = io.connect();

client.on('connect', function() {
  //Some events
})
```

Comment: Might be unrelated but I see this pretty consistently, I don't believe you should be calling `connect` on the client side. The method to connect back to the server should be `var client = io();`

Comment: Did you try with just that minimal code you've posted? That will help isolate the problem.

Comment: @pay I've tried with the events inside the "connect" and outside of it. Doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @mscdex I've tried reducing to a minimum, but have not tried with just the snippets in the post. I will try and get back to you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. I meant the method you use to connect to the server from the client, where you have `var client = io.connect();`  I believe it should be `var client = io();`

Comment: I was referring to the `client.on('connect')`; misread your comment. I've tried replacing `io.connect()` with simply `io()` and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Stripping to the bare minimum doesn't change anything either. However, downgrading to Socket.io v0.9.16 (as it was before) seems to solve the issue... I don't want to downgrade though :(

Comment: Are you using websockets as transport mechanism? Browsers generally limit the number of concurrent requests to the same host (across all tabs), I wonder if it may have something to do with that. `socket.io@1` changed the initial handshake with the server (starts by using a polling mechanism and then upgrade to websockets if available), so I wonder if those initial polling requests get stuck because of the limit.

Comment: @robertklep I don't restrict to any specific transport, so it's upgrading to websockets after the handshake. What's weird is that if I remove the "bouncy" proxy, the problem goes away. However, I really can't get rid of it. I tried to replace bouncy with node-http-proxy but the problem remains.. :(

Comment: What exactly are you proxying?

Comment: The users can start games (which are other node servers) that are available at a specific port. They then use a url like 5555.domain.com to be redirected to the game running on port 5555. The proxy takes care of the redirecting. I don't really know why they decided to do it like this in the first place (instead of using URLs like domain.com:5555).

Comment: I think my predecessors decided to do it like this because the only open port is 80. I guess the proxy redirection bypasses that?

Answer (score 0):

your binding before the server is listening, try something like this

```
var app = express();
server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port ' + PORT + '!');
});

io.listen(server);
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The server runs fine both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replace the bouncy module with nginx. See my other question for the solution.

[nginx : redirect to port according to domain prefix (dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808860/nginx-redirect-to-port-according-to-domain-prefix-dynamically)